# Vector spaces with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have the vector space $V=\mathbb P_5$,

and I have $W$ which is a subspace of $W$ such that

$W=\{p(x)\in \mathbb P_5|p(0)=p(1)=p(2)\}$

I am asked the following:

"Let $u(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)$, and explain why for every $ q \in W$ there exists $r \in \mathbb P_2$ such that $q(x)=u(x)\cdot r(x) + q(0)$"

First of all what is this even asking? I am a little confused about that. I think I have to sub spaces here somehow but I am not sure at all. How would I even begin to approach this question?

Thanks for any input or help... My linear algebra is really rusty as I am doing is after 4 years.

Comment: The question is either asking you to prove or just intuitively argue for the statement: If $q \in W$ and $u(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)$, then there exists an $r$ such that $q(x) = u(x)r(x) + q(0)$ for all $x$.

Comment: I figured that much but what is q and r defined as in this question?

Comment: Have you seen the [Polynomial Division Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division)?

Comment: $q$ is any polynomial of degree less than or equal to $5$ such that $q(0)=q(1)=q(2)$.  $r$ is some arbitrary polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2$.

Comment: Yes. I actually used that theorem in a another part of the same question. I am seeing it too but I am not sure if there is a way to actually relate the theorem in any way into this.

Comment: No. I am just not seeing it. Could I get a hint please?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r\in P_2$ exists if and only if $q(x) - q(0)$ is a multiple of $x(x-1)(x-2)$ (just rearrange the equation to see this).

So the question becomes "why is $q(x)-q(0)$ a multiple of $x(x-1)(x-2)$?"  Well, recall that $x-a$ is a factor of a polynomial if and only if $a$ is a root of that polynomial.

So then this reduces the problem again, this time to "are $0$, $1$, and $2$ roots of $q(x)-q(0)$?"  Of course they are -- just evaluate the polynomial $q(x)-q(0)$ at $x=0$ to get $q(0)-q(0)=0$.  But because $q\in W$ we also know that $q(0) = q(1)=q(2)$ and so $q(1)-q(0) = 0 = q(2) - q(0)$ as well.  I.e. $0$, $1$, and $2$ are all roots of $q(x) - q(0)$.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I already got it on my own though :) .

Answer (score 1):

The condition $q\in W$ means that $q(0)=q(1)=q(2)$, so that the new polynomial $p(x):=q(x)-q(0)$ has at least three roots, at $x=0,1,2$. Apply division algorithm to $p$ divided by $u$ for the result.

Comment: Why is $p(x):=q(x)-q(0)$ true?

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty What do you mean by true? I defined a new polynomial.

Comment: Ohh you defined it. Okay I see. Sorry. I'm just trying to understand this bit by bit.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_based_on_equality In case you don't know, the symbol ":=" is one of the commonly used symbol for "is defined as".

Comment: Well all I can think of saying is that the condition follows directly as a consequence of the polynomial division theorem so therefore, the condition in the question is true by definition. I am not sure if that's okay though.

Comment: No I don't think that's right. Could I get a hint please?

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty go to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) to discuss further. This is getting too long

Comment: I got it now. Never mind.